# Solving $\text{key}=(\sum_{K=0}^n\frac{1}{a^K})\bmod m$ with High limits

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

I was solving this equation:
$$\text{key}=\left(\sum_{K=0}^n\frac{1}{a^K}\right)\bmod{m}.$$

#### Given

$$ 1,000,000,000 < a, n, m \; < 5,000,000,000, $$
$$ a, m \text{ are coprime}. $$

I solved it by brute force, but it won't work in the given constrains so I need a faster algorithm or is there is something I can notice to make the formula easier to solve ?

Answer (score 6):

Solve [a linear homogeneous recurrence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) to obtain the identity $$\sum_{K=0}^n\frac1{a^K}=\begin{cases}\frac{1-1/a^{n+1}}{1-1/a}&\text{if }a\neq1\pmod m\\n+1&\text{if }a=1\pmod m\end{cases}$$ and use efficient algorithms for [multiplicative inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) and [exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) mod $m$.

Comment: I can't recurrence through N .. It's at least 1,000,000,000
Or do you mean something else ..
I've solved it already using this using the following recurrences
$ S(2k)=S(k)(1+q^k)$ and $ S(2k+1)=q S(2k) +1$

where $ q = ModularMultiplicativeInverse( a ) $ and Got Accepted :)

Comment: You do not need to recurse, your formula (without mod) is just a sum of a geometric series and has a solution in a closed form as shown in the answer. Then you have to carry out all operations mod m.